# Adding Up str input

Tags: python

Im getting an error saying I cant multiply sequences by non-int of type(str) which is confusing me because all I wanted to do is multiply the 2 str(input)'s together, I tried finding resources on the internet and nothing to be seen.

```
length = str(input("Enter length (cm): "))
width = str(input("Enter the width (cm):"))
area = [( width * length )+"cm"]
print("The area of the rectangle is"+ area)
```

Comment: Can we get full traceback?

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  Therefore `length` and `width` are strings.  You can't multiply two strings.

Comment: You cannot multiply strings. `"3" * "4"` is as nonsensical as `"sad" * "also"`.  You must convert you data to integers or floats with `int()` or `float()` for multiplication to work.  Note that even if you had the correct data types `area = [( width * length )+"cm"]` would return a single item list.  You'll probably want to remove those brackets if you just want a number.

Comment: Presumably you meant to put `int()`, not `str()`, around the input statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did wrong is that you are trying to multiply strings and not integers, when getting input, stored value is a string. You need integers for this task so convert input to int with simple `int(input())`.

Here is the code that you need to use:

```
def main():
    try:
        length = int(input("Enter the length (cm): "))
        width = int(input("Enter the width (cm):"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Input should be only numbers!")
        main()
        return
    area = width * length
    print(f"The area of the rectangle is {area} cm.")

main()
```

Added: Exception to prevent people from typing strings in input field.